# When there are multiple users to access the page at the same time, do I need to add synchronization key word in my contrlloer method?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, concurrency

I know that the default way is singleton.Now I have a requirement.In my controller method,I want to update my data and then lock the data.Before user update the data,I will judge whether he can update or not  according to the other table field status.
  For example: If user A visit the data,he may update the data value to 1 ,and I lock the data by update the status field which means the other people can not update .and then do other operation like delete some user A files. But in the same time,may be user B visit the data,he may update the data value to 2.And do I may delete user B file too?
  Do I need to  add  synchronized key word in my controller method? Or tomcat server or spring mvc have help me to deal with this problem? Now what I want is only one user can update the data and only delete one use file.

Comment: Your question would be easier to read if you inserted a space after each period and comma.

Answer (score 1):

MVC Controller methods generally should not be synchronized because controllers generally should not multithreaded. Also, "I know that the default way is singleton" - the default way for what? Controllers generally do not need to be singleton​s. Controllers should not handle the business logic; that's the job of the model (the "M" in "MVC"). The resource manager, or component that handles all that table logic you described, probably should not be multithreaded either. A single-threaded resource manager is far less confusing. And it needn't be a singleton either. Just instantiate one of them, is all. (A resource manager might need more than one instance possible, e.g., to manage more than one resource.)

You should show us your code.

Comment: Controllers  invoke service,I means add sychronized key word add controller or service.' controllers generally should not multithreaded'.Many user visit the website at the same time ,This kind of phenomenon is quite normal.